# Sum times from xml with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an xml-file containing time-consumtion of my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StandardPerformanceTrackerReport>
<Line133783 id="2024-03-13 12:07:35,253" operationTimeInSeconds="0,078" operationName="updateStation">
  <Line133786 id="2024-03-13 12:07:35,253" operationTimeInSeconds="0,078" operationName="GetFeatureUsingRelationInfo">
    <Line133791 id="2024-03-13 12:07:35,253" operationTimeInSeconds="0,078" operationName="GetOutputRecordSet">
       <Line133792 id="2024-03-13 12:07:35,253" operationTimeInSeconds="0,078" operationName="GetRelatedRecordset">
         <Line133801 id="2024-03-13 12:07:35,253" operationTimeInSeconds="0,078" operationName="Execute">
           <Line133802 id="2024-03-13 12:07:35,253" operationTimeInSeconds="0,078" operationName="GetOutputRecordSetForFieldValues">
             <Line133813 id="2024-03-13 12:07:35,253" operationTimeInSeconds="0,078" operationName="IsNullOrEmpty" />
             <Line133814 id="2024-03-13 12:08:35,253" operationTimeInSeconds="1" operationName="MyFunction" />
           </Line133802>
           <Line133813 id="2024-03-13 12:09:35,253" operationTimeInSeconds="1" operationName="IsNullOrEmpty" />
         </Line133801>
       </Line133792>
     </Line133791>
   </Line133786>
 </Line133783>
<StandardPerformanceTrackerReport>
```

The file is actually way bigger and can contain any arbitrary nesting of operations.

Now I want to get the total `operationTimeInSeconds` for each function, e.g. the above `IsNullOrEmpty`-function occurs tiwce in the file. Once with `0.078` seconds and once with one second, so the overall should be `1.078` seconds.

I tried to do this with powershell:

```
Select-Xml -Path ".\PerformanceTracking.xml" -XPath //*[@operationName] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Group-Object operationName | %{New-Object psobject -Property @{ Name=$_.Name; Count=$_.Count; Sum=($_.Group | Measure-Object operationTimeInSeconds -Sum).Sum }}
```

However that only returns the `operationName`s, not their `Count` nor their total time. How can I display the name, count and total time for every function?

Comment: Can you add a valid XML for testing?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Group-Object` to group the nodes by `operationName`, then make sure you parse the `operationTimeInSeconds` value as a `[decimal]`:

```
# gather relevant nodes from xml document
$opNodes = Select-Xml -Path .\PerformanceTracking.xml -XPath '//*[@operationName]'|ForEach-Object Node

# group by ops name
$opNodesGroupedByName = $opNodes |Group-Object -Property operationName

# calculate cumulative time per group
$opNodesGroupedByName |Select-Object Name,Count,@{
  Name = 'CumulativeTimeInSeconds'
  Expression = {
    $_.Group |ForEach-Object {
      # parse the value as a [double] 
      # [NumberStyles]::AllowDecimalPoint will ensure correct parsing of `,` as decimal separator even if locale uses `.` 
      [decimal]::Parse($_.operationTimeInSeconds , [System.Globalization.NumberStyles]::AllowDecimalPoint)
    } |Measure-Object -Sum |ForEach-Object Sum
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get why parsing to decimal should do what I want., if the property isn't just selected.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Because `1 + "0,078"` might be interpreted as `1 + 78` depending on locale. I'm not sure what you mean by "if the property isn't just selected"

Comment: well, that's just  a formatting-issue (I'm not even sure if I have that issue at all). However that doesn't solve my issue, that only the `operationName` is displayed, but neither the `Count` nor the `TotalTime`.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain If you want the resulting property name to be `TotalTime`, change `Name = 'CumulativeTimeInSeconds'` to `Name = 'TotalTime'`. I've updated the answer to include the count as well

Comment: Nice, but `[NumberStyles]::AllowDecimalPoint` uses the current culture's decimal mark; e.g. `[decimal]::parse("0,078", [System.Globalization.NumberStyles]::AllowDecimalPoint)` fails on my en-US system. Here's what works (picking a culture known to use `,`): `[decimal]::parse("0,078", [cultureinfo] 'nl')`